# Is quitting apps bad for my iPhone battery?

Tags: iphone, battery

Last night at dinner one of my Android using friends was bragging about how their Samsung phone had an option to tap one button to quickly shut down all your apps. My other friend (an iPhone user like me) responded with "Why would you wanna do that? It'll just flatten your battery quicker!".

Is this true and why?